# How do I print a triangle of stars using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Is it practically possible to create a triangle of stars like this as below in PL/SQL. I know that this could be done easily in any other programming language like C,C++,Java but want to know whether it is really possible with just SQL or PL/SQL. This is for my homework and I should use conditional clauses (IF THEN ELSE), loops(FOR, WHILE).

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
```

and

```
*****
 ***
  *
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: According to question tags, MS SQL Server

Comment: @FabianPijcke But according to error, Oracle.

Comment: Oh I did not follow that discussion... Indeed :o

Comment: I am using toad for oracle

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
The first loop will print the stars in triangle and the second loop will reverse it.

In **PL/SQL:**

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. :p
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (LPAD (LPAD ('*', i, '*'), :p + 1, ' '));

   END LOOP;
    FOR i IN 1 .. :p
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (LPAD (LPAD ('*', :p-i, '*'), :p + 1, ' '));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

In **SQL:**

```
    SELECT LPAD (LPAD ('*', level, '*'), :p + 1, ' ') a
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :p;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done purely in sql (in Oracle), like so:

```
SELECT RPAD(' ', :p_num_triangle_rows - LEVEL) || RPAD('*', LEVEL * 2 -1, '*') || RPAD(' ', :p_num_triangle_rows - LEVEL) triangle
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :p_num_triangle_rows
ORDER BY CASE WHEN :p_ascending_or_descending = 'a' THEN LEVEL END ASC,
         CASE WHEN :p_ascending_or_descending = 'd' THEN LEVEL END DESC;
```

p_num_triangle_rows := 20, p_ascending_or_desc := 'a':

```
TRIANGLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   *
                  ***
                 *****
                *******
               *********
              ***********
             *************
            ***************
           *****************
          *******************
         *********************
        ***********************
       *************************
      ***************************
     *****************************
    *******************************
   *********************************
  ***********************************
 *************************************
***************************************
```

p_num_triangle_rows := 3, p_ascending_or_desc := 'd':

```
TRIANGLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*****
 ***
  *
```

---

ETA: Here is a PL/SQL version that will do what you're after:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE produce_triangle_rows (p_num_triangle_rows IN NUMBER,
                                   p_ascending_or_descending IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'a')
  IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('p_num_triangle_rows = '|| p_num_triangle_rows ||', p_ascending_or_descending = ' || p_ascending_or_descending);
    FOR i IN 1..p_num_triangle_rows
    LOOP
      CASE WHEN p_ascending_or_descending = 'a' THEN
                dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(' ', p_num_triangle_rows - i) || RPAD('*', i * 2 - 1, '*') || RPAD(' ', p_num_triangle_rows - i));
           WHEN p_ascending_or_descending = 'd' THEN
                dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(' ', i - 1) || RPAD('*', 2 * (p_num_triangle_rows - i) + 1, '*') || RPAD(' ', i - 1));
      END CASE;
    END LOOP;
  END produce_triangle_rows;
BEGIN
  produce_triangle_rows(p_num_triangle_rows => 5,
                        p_ascending_or_descending => 'a');

  produce_triangle_rows(p_num_triangle_rows => 3,
                        p_ascending_or_descending => 'd');
END;
/


p_num_triangle_rows = 5, p_ascending_or_descending = a
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********

p_num_triangle_rows = 3, p_ascending_or_descending = d
*****
 *** 
  *
```

Note that I've wrapped the procedure in an anonymous block purely so I could call it with different parameters. You would just create the produce_triangle_rows procedure on its own and then call it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @count int,@num int,@num1 int, @space int, @str varchar(50)
set @count = 3 set @num = 1
while(@num<=@count)
begin
  set @num1 = 0 set @space = @count-@num
  while (@num1<@num)
  begin
   if @str is null
    set @str = '* '
   else
    set @str = @str+'* '   set @num1 = @num1+1
  end
print (space(@space)+@str)
set @num = @num+1   set @str = null
end
```

Or

```
Declare @x varchar(20)=0,@y varchar(20)=5
while(@y>0)
begin
print space(@y)+replicate('*',@x)+replicate('*',@x+1)
set @y=@y-1
set @x=@x+1
end
```

Comment: ı had a error like this---> ORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior

Comment: Which version of mssql are you using

Comment: I am using toad for oracle

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem fun, so I solved it in PostgreSQL. Unfortunately repeating characters seems not really be a standardized feature. Here are the syntax to use for the most common RDBMSes:

- PostgreSQL : `repeat('*', n)`
- Oracle : `rpad('', n, '*')`
- MS SQL Server : `replicate('*', n)`
- MySQL : `repeat('*', n)`

First create some table with numbers up to whatever is the biggest triangle you can imagine:

```
create table n10 (n) as
  select 0 union
  select 1 union
  select 2 union
  select 3 union
  select 4 union
  select 5 union
  select 6 union
  select 7 union
  select 8 union
  select 9;

create table n1000 (n) as
  select 100 * a1.n + 10 * a2.n + a3.n
  from n10 a1 cross join n10 a2 cross join n10 a3;
```

Then to make a triangle of size 5 (replace 5 by any number between 0 and 1000 you want):

```
with s (s) as (select 5)
select
  repeat(' ', s - n - 1) ||
  repeat('*', 2 * n + 1) ||
  repeat(' ', s - n - 1)
from n1000 cross join s
where n < s
order by n;

with s (s) as (select 5)
select
  repeat(' ', s - n - 1) ||
  repeat('*', 2 * n + 1) ||
  repeat(' ', s - n - 1)
from n1000 cross join s
where n < s
order by n desc;
```